# Adding a mile buffer onto a shapefile

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a shapefile of universities and colleges that can be found here:

https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/bc7ef39f9d2a4605b9d5aad0e050af11/explore?location=30.280984%2C-97.732610%2C14.74

The objective is to run that shapefile through a dataset of individual lat/long coordinates to see which ones fall within the confines of a university shapefile. So those coordinates would be stores in a dataset called `id_coordinates`

```
id_coordinates <- st_as_sf(id_coordinates, coords = c("id_longitude", "id_latitude"), crs = 4326)
```

Then we open up the shapefile itself:

```
# Set the file paths for the shapefiles
college_fp <- "Colleges_and_Universities_Campuses/CollegeUniversityCampuses.shp"

# Read in the shapefiles
college_sf <- st_read(college_fp) %>% filter(STATE == 'VA')
```

Then we transform `id_coordinates` to be consistent with `college_sf`

```
id_coordinates_transform <- st_transform(pa_vf, st_crs(college_sf))
```

Then we join them together to see which IDs have a lat/long that falls within the borders of a shapefile:

```
results_join <- st_join(id_coordinates_transform, college_sf, join = st_within)
```

But what would I do if I wanted to create an additional one mile radius "buffer" around the shapefile found in `college_sf`? What would that look like?

EDIT: Using the `st_buffer` function, but that seems to be making it way too big?

```
buffer_radius <- 1609.34
college_sf_buffer <- st_buffer(college_sf, dist = buffer_radius)
```

Comment: Have you tried `st_buffer`? If so, what went wrong? If not, that's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I did try that, but that seems to be making the buffer way too big? Am I doing that correctly?

Comment: FYI I added it to the "EDIT" section in my question

Comment: I think you just need to specify the correct units for the buffer. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the units of an `st_buffer`:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tidyverse)

college_sf <- st_read(college_fp) |> filter(STATE == 'VA') 

college_sf_buffer <- st_buffer(college_sf, dist = units::set_units(1609.34, m))
```

This appears to give reasonable results:

```r
college_sf_buffer |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(fill = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Without disagreeing with the principle of the answer - on contrary! - I suggest that the OP consideres the definition of buffer in miles. `college_sf_buffer <- st_buffer(college_sf, dist = units::set_units(1, "mile"))`. It will be somewhat (likely negligibly, but still) more accurate than thinking of a mile as 1609.34 meters.

Comment: @JindraLacko fair point - although a mile is exactly 1609.344 metres by definition so we could use that instead if keen to stick to metric measurements for whatever reason.

Comment: thanks for the correction then! I always struggle with the imperial units / it all feels like shillings per pound to me